# How to aggregate a stream of inputs from a kafka topic?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to read in from a topic where i then apply a window of 5minutes to aggregate the input into one long string and output this long string into a different topic.

The current code i have is:

```
        //KStream<String, String> DistPrep = DistanceSource0.flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(value.split(",")));
        DistanceSource0.groupByKey()
        .windowedBy(SlidingWindows.withTimeDifferenceAndGrace(Duration.ofMillis(300000), Duration.ofMillis(0)))
        .aggregate(() -> "0", (key, value, points) -> points + "," + value)
        .toStream().peek((key, value) -> System.out.println("Outgoing: " + key + " value: " + value)).to("distanceTest");
```

The issue im having is when is no output is coming out after i aggregate and toStream(). I have used peek() on the stream coming out of DistanceSource0 and can see that i am getting records in, but there is an issue when i try to aggregate the records together.

Any advice on where my issue is coming from would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have a consumer console open at the destination topic and have been unable to observe anything either.

Comment: Try to use thumbling or hopping window, sliding windows have quite different features.